# loud fan on laptop

Tags: laptop, fan

My laptop (hp dv6500t) fan is really loud! What can I do to decrease the sound? I checked the bios with no options and I can't used speedfna because it doesn't work. Can I chagbe it's faN

Edit: I already cleaned out the fans and even added artic silver 5. It's loud where people can hear it accross the classroom.

Comment: btw, just how  loud is it ? can you compare it with something, as to give us the approximation ?

Comment: If the fans too expensive to replace new, I'd suggest looking for a 'dead' one on ebay that you can use as a donor for parts.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing "easy".

1. depending on what control you have over your cpu temp/voltage/fan speed you can try decreasing it
2. you can try opening up your laptop and cleaning it (the fan, not the laptop, although ou might want to look at the air entry and exit points as well)
3. you can take it to a service/repair shop and ask them to change it ... although laptops usually have standardized parts so if this one was made that way, the other one will be the same. No much choice in fans when it comes to branded machines.

Comment: On a laptop I do not recommend decreasing the fan speed.  Laptops get hot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an bios update? - We had some IBM work stations who's fans would go nuts at random times. The update must have corrected thermal settings to calm them down.

---

There's a potential that your fan is clogged up with dust and has to work a lot harder to dissipate the heat.

When cleaning the fan, make sure you use something to stop the fan spinning. If using a vacuum cleaner or canned air you could spin the fan way in excess of what it was built to spin at.

HP has always been good with service manuals, you can find [the one for your model here](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01295877.pdf)

Ak